# Vectors: Finding third point in a right angle triangle

Tags: vector-analysis

Given A(1,4) and B (3,-5) use the dot product to find point C so that triangle ABC is a right angle triangle.

Comment: I take it that this is an exercise in using the dot product - to find a right-angled triangle using only grid lines pick (1,-5) or (3,4) - draw a diagram to see how this works. Circle geometry tells you that the points you get will lie on the circle with diameter $AB$ - so your dot product should generate an equation for that circle.

Comment: @MarkBennet If we ignore the position of the right angle for a moment, there will be a lot more solutions than just on that circle. Points on the two perpendiculars through $A$ and $B$ to the segment joining the two points would work. I'm not sure if there is any convention governing the labeling of "a right triangle ABC", but it seems like the problem was probably asking to consider one of those perpendicular lines...

Comment: @jacqueline Does the labeling $ABC$ require the right angle to be at $A$, $B$ or $C$? Or do you not care?

Answer (score 2):

Just put $(C-A).(B-A)=0$, that should solve it. Note that there are infinitely many such triangles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! it might help to provide some more details in your answer. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Find the vector connecting between the two:

$$\vec{c}=<1-3,4+5>=<-2,9>$$

You can use the dot product between $\vec{c}$ and a unit vector $\hat{b}=<-1,0>$:
$$\cos{\theta}=\frac{\vec{c}\cdot\hat{b}}{||\vec{c}||\space||\hat{b}||}$$

The length of the opposing two angles are $||\vec{c}||\sin{\theta}$ and $||\vec{c}||\cos{\theta}$.